# How we render two value in UIWebView

Tags: ios

I want scale the UIWebview and increase font size . I am newer in iOS. Please Help.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [webView scalesPageToFit];
    float scale = 52990/webView.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%f%%'", scale];
    int fontValue = 200;
    NSString *webviewFontSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')",fontValue];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:webviewFontSize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about CSS manipulation. `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` gives you a chance to run a piece of javascript code based on your html content. If you can adjust font size in a common web page, you can do it here.